# How to create sitemap with dynamic sub sitemap structure in django?

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I'm trying create a dynamic generate sitemap in django and i hit the wall.
Action I'm trying to code:

- in url.py i have url: **re_path(r'sitemap-jobs.xml$'...)**
- the above web address triggers function: **MonthlyJobsSitemap** in sitemap dict whose create sub sitemap divided by months like: **http:/host/sitemap-pl-jobs-2022-01.xml**

The result is address in robots.txt sitemap: /sitemap-pl-jobs.xml. After entering there are files splitted on monthly files: /sitemap-pl-jobs.xml-2022-01.
And after entering the monthly sitemap i wanna see addresses to jobs published on web site.

I don't have problem with create one sitemap with all jobs but i have to split it into monthly sitemaps.

Someone have any idea how to code that in django?

Comment: re_path use regex in urls so you can input your regex to handle these cases.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi yeah, i know but when i add (?<year>.+)-(?<month>.+) into address how can i generate sub sitemap structure nested into main sitemap-jobs.xml url?